# How does one write the standard model Lagrangian in other smaller Lagrangian counterparts?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model

How does one write the [standard model Lagrangian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model_%28mathematical_formulation%29) in other smaller Lagrangian counterparts? Before electroweak symmetry breaking by the Higgs Mechanism:

$L_{EW} = L_{g} + L_{f} + L_{h} + L_{y}$

Where

$ L_{g} $ describes the interaction between the three W particles and the B particle.

$ L_{g} = -W_{a}^{\muν}W_{\muν}^{a}/4 - B^{\muν}B_{\muν}/4$

$ L_{f} $ is the kinetic term for the Standard Model fermions.

$ L_{h} $ is the Higgs Field Lagrangian.

$ L_{y} $ gives the Yukawa interaction that generates fermion masses after the Higgs acquires a vacuum expectation value.

After electroweak symmetry breaking by Higgs mechanism:

$L_{EW} = L_{K} + L_{N} + L_{C} + L_{H} + L_{HV} + L_{WWV} + L_{WWVV} + L_{Y}$

What the terms mean can be obtained by a simple Google Search, as I will not list them out here.

My question is therefore this:

$ L_{SM} = \space???$

It consists of

[image: terms of SM Lagrangian]

How do I express these terms in their respective shorthand form?
The first term $ -B^{\muν}B_{\muν}/4 $ happens to be the 2nd half of $ L_{g} $, so it is well understood if it was represented as $L_{U1}$?

How about the rest?

Comment: [Related question on Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Lagrangian-of-the-Standard-Model).

Comment: Yes, I've looked at it but it does not provide the specific terms of the Lagrangian and their association, so it was rather unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{L}_{SM}=\mathcal{L}_{Dirac}+\mathcal{L}_{mass}+\mathcal{L}_{guage}+\mathcal{L}_{guage/\psi}$$

Comment: U(1), SU(2) and SU(3) terms are probably parts of other Lagrangian terms, as they are not Lagrangians themselves.

Comment: @Lagrangian Refer to guage theory